# android spinner doesn't show indicator for android verison lesser than 5.0

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm using the AppCompat, the EditText uses the material desgin style with a single indicator below it, but my problem is with the spinner it shows nothing except selectableItemBackground icon, that is the drop down icon. If i use a custom background drawable with a line shape, then the drop down icon doesn't show again. I really don't know if i have used the best words to explain my problem but i will be glad if someone can help out.

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/hb_sign_up_sex"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                />
```

[image: The Item and SubITem is a spinner but it has no indicator. Even when i run it on my phone]

**EDITED**
This is what i want to achieve::
Something exactly similar to the DropDown in the picture
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the background property as dropdown,

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
```

Update your xml as follows ,

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/hb_sign_up_sex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            />
```

Comment: Thanks fo you kind and quick response.. I updated my XML the result is pretty okay if do a little work around... but please can you look at the edited question that describes what i really want to achieve.

Comment: i think providing date/time through spinner is not good idea, that's why Android has date/time picker. Spinner is for limited data sets. How do you load all dates into list if you going to use spinner ?

Comment: thanks.. but I'm not actually using it for a date, i want to use it for just plain dropdown list but i need the spinner style to look like whats in the image. The Issue is not what i'm using it for,the issue here is the Design and how to achieve it.

Comment: if so, you can achieve that through above property. where are you stuck now ?

Comment: The one your provided is fine, but it looks like a button with the dropown icon, if only i can make the background of it transparent and then have only its bottom border show... then i'd be fine.